# Why did it successfully set up a modal?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyqt6

An attempt was made to output a dialog containing the image when a thread signal occurred.
NonModal was not applied when setWindowModality was set, but when I changed the code as follows, NonModal was applied.

I will introduce the code in before after.

before

```py
    @Slot(QImage)
    def concatImgShow(self, image):
        image_window = QDialog()
        image_window.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModality.NonModal)
        image_window.setWindowTitle("camera monitor")

        label = QLabel(self.image_window)
        pixmap = QPixmap(image)
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.show()

        image_window.setFixedSize(image.width(), image.height())
        # image_window.setModal(False)
        image_window.exec()
```

after

```py
class window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUI()
        self.image_window = QDialog()

    @Slot(QImage)
    def concatImgShow(self, image):
        self.image_window.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModality.NonModal)
        self.image_window.setWindowTitle("camera monitor")

        label = QLabel(self.image_window)
        pixmap = QPixmap(image)
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.show()

        self.image_window.setFixedSize(image.width(), image.height())
        # image_window.setModal(False)
        self.image_window.show()
```

What I did was, I just moved `Self.image_window = QDialog()` to `def_init\_()`.

Why is the `setWindowModality` setting successful?

Additional Information :

1. In the before code, the `show()` method did not work(Goes to the next interpreter even if `show()` run it), so we used `exec()`.

Comment: No, you didn't "just moved". Using `show()` is not the same as calling `exec()`, as the [`exec()` documentation clearly says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec): "Shows the dialog as a *modal dialog*, blocking until the user closes it". If you call `show()`, the dialog will have the modality set (or implied); if you call `exec()` (or `open()`), the dialog will **always** be modal.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I noticed the difference between `show()` and `exec()`.
The actual problem is 'self' when 'show()' is used.I think that 'QLabel' was not printed due to the difference in 'self`

Comment: That is irrelevant to the problem at hand, and it's caused by the fact that `exec()` is blocking until the dialog is closed, while `show` isn't; when the function exits, your label gets garbage collected because it's a local variable. You should make it persistent (for instance making it an instance member) and eventually close it when the dialog is (see the documentation for related signals).